# Comparação de datetime usando Laravel eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

Olá, eu estou tendo problemas no uso do eloquent do Laravel para criar um SQL que atendesse a seguinte demanda: "retornar uma consulta caso haja uma reserva feita em um determinado período de tempo";
A seguir o código da minha função que, verifica se já foi feito uma reserva para aquele determinado período

```
private function isOut($timeIn, $timeOut)
{
    $timeIn = date_format(date_create($timeIn), 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $timeOut = date_format(date_create($timeOut), 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $output = new Output();
    $query = $output->select('*')
        ->where('users_id', Auth::user()->id)
        ->where(function($q) use ($timeIn,$timeOut){
            $q->orWhere(function($s) use ($timeIn,$timeOut){
                $s->whereDate('start_at','>=',$timeIn)
                ->whereDate('start_at','<=',$timeOut);
            })->orWhere(function ($s) use ($timeIn, $timeOut){
                $s->whereDate('end_at','>=',$timeIn)
                ->whereDate('end_at','<=',$timeOut);
            });
        })
        ->get()
        ->toArray();
    return $query;
}
```

Como dito acima, o objetivo dela é verificar se no intervalo de tempo de start_at e end_at há alguma reserva feita. Como base, para esse código eu criei o seguinte SQL:

```
select * from `outputs` 
where `users_id` = 1 
AND (
        (
            `start_at` >= CONVERT('2019-03-09 13:00:00',DATETIME) 
             AND `start_at` <=  CONVERT('2019-03-10 13:00:00',DATETIME)
        )
    OR  
        (
            `end_at` >= CONVERT('2019-03-09 13:00:00',DATETIME) 
             AND `end_at` <=  CONVERT('2019-03-10 13:00:00',DATETIME)
        )
    )
and `outputs`.`deleted_at` is NULL
```

Porém, esse é o código que eu peguei no debbuger relativo ao que eu escrevi acima:

```
select * from `outputs` 
where `users_id` = 1 
AND (
        (
            DATE (`start_at`) >= '2019-03-09 13:00:00'  
            AND DATE(`start_at`) <= '2019-03-10 13:00:00'
        ) 
    OR 
        (
            DATE(`end_at`) >= '2019-03-09 13:00:00' 
            AND DATE(`end_at`) <= '2019-03-10 13:00:00'
        )
    ) 
and `outputs`.`deleted_at` is null
```

Então minha duvida, para trabalhar com datas, não achei outra forma se não o uso do ->whereDate() no Laravel, porém essa função não consegue atender a demanda, pois acredito que ele está apenas olhando para o formato DATE da string, sendo necessário considerar DATETIME, em resumo: Há alguma outra forma de usar DATETIME no Laravel, ou há algo que eu deixei passar relativo a comparação de datas pelo framework?

Comment: Tem que estar dentro das duas datas? não seria `between`, exemplo: `$data between start_at and end_at`?

Comment: nem chego a acreditar que funcionou, a noia era tanto em procurar por um jeito de garantir que o mysql iria ler a string como DATETIME que nem cheguei a tentar o basico, realmente obrigado

Comment: Coloque como resposta a solução encontrada ... !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agradecimentos e credito a [Virgilio Novic](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/54880/virgilio-novic)

Me preocupei tanto em garantir que a string fosse vista como DATETIME que não considerei que a formatação padrão do Mysql é interpretada por ele mesmo como um objeto DATETIME se o valor estiver sem aspas.

Nesse caso between resolve perfeitamente minha necessidade:

```
private function isOut($timeIn, $timeOut)
{
    $timeIn = date_format(date_create($timeIn), 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $timeOut = date_format(date_create($timeOut), 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $output = new Output();
    $query = $output->select('*')
        ->where('users_id', Auth::user()->id)
        ->where(function($q) use ($timeIn,$timeOut){
            $q->orWhere(function($s) use ($timeIn,$timeOut){
                $s->whereBetween('start_at',[$timeIn,$timeOut]);
            })->orWhere(function ($s) use ($timeIn, $timeOut){
                $s->whereBetween('end_at',[$timeIn,$timeOut]);
            });
        })
        ->get()
        ->toArray();
    return $query;
}
```